# How do I clear this array each time the inner loop finishes?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I need some help with these async loops. Each object has a materials array inside. I need to clear objectRedirects each time the materials loop ends.

```
  objects.map(async object => {
      objectRedirects = [];

      await Promise.all(
        object.materials.map(async material => {
          const childObject = await ItemObject.findOne({
            name: object.name,
            material: material
          })
            .lean()
            .exec();

          objectRedirects.push(childObject);
        })
      );
    });
```

Currently objectRedirects will never be cleared or reset back to an empty array it will continue adding the 'materials' of each 'object'

Comment: Can you provide more details? It's not clear to me what you're trying to achieve. Typically, you'd use a separate array for each `materials`. More details about the problem and a [mcve] would make it easier to offer an answer that makes sense.

Comment: @ggorlen Each iteration of an object I want to iterate through the materials of each object adding it to an array called 'objectRedirects'. After the iteration of the materials has completed and the 'objectRedirects' has been filled. The next object in the iteration starts and the 'objectRedirects' variable is wiped/reset back to a blank array.

Comment: OK, I get that you *want* to wipe the array clean after each iteration, but I suspect that's more of a means to an end than the end itself. What do you really want to achieve by doing that? See [x-y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Because I will add each object to the database with it's respective redirects

Comment: There you go. I would recommend editing your question to ask about that directly ("How to do I do X? Here's what I tried.") rather than your attempted solution ("How to do I do Y?").

Answer (score 0):

You need two `Promise.all`s, one for each `object` in `objects`, and one for each item in an object's `materials` array. Then, the `.map` will create a new inner array on each iteration. (`.map` should not be used for side-effects - use it to create another array)

```
const arrayOfObjectMaterialsArray = await Promise.all(objects.map(object => Promise.all(
  object.materials.map(material => (
    ItemObject.findOne({
      name: object.name,
      material: material
    })
      .lean()
      .exec()
  ))
)));
```

You may just return the Promise from each `.map` callback alone - no need for the inner functions to be `async`